# What is going on with my networking?

Tags: networking

I just recently discovered that there is some networking issue with my ubuntu server. Its using up all my internet bandwidth and when I type ifconfig I get this

```
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.224.1  P-t-P:172.27.224.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t1     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.225.1  P-t-P:172.27.225.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t2     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.226.1  P-t-P:172.27.226.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t3     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.227.1  P-t-P:172.27.227.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t4     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.228.1  P-t-P:172.27.228.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t5     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.229.1  P-t-P:172.27.229.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t6     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.230.1  P-t-P:172.27.230.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t7     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.231.1  P-t-P:172.27.231.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t8     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.232.1  P-t-P:172.27.232.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t9     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.233.1  P-t-P:172.27.233.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t10    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.234.1  P-t-P:172.27.234.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t11    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.235.1  P-t-P:172.27.235.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t12    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.236.1  P-t-P:172.27.236.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t13    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.237.1  P-t-P:172.27.237.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t14    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.238.1  P-t-P:172.27.238.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t15    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.27.239.1  P-t-P:172.27.239.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:ee:62:d6
      inet addr:192.168.1.40  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feee:62d6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:13731996 errors:0 dropped:14 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10867365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:5507965178 (5.5 GB)  TX bytes:11696834327 (11.6 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:10491723 (10.4 MB)  TX bytes:10491723 (10.4 MB)
```

Comment: The device `as0t[n]` should be created from OpenVPN (or a similar VPN server/cleint). Anything within the VPN seems to be configured (routed) wrong, and the traffic goes though your server ... I think, based on your question, you are not aware a VPN is running on your system? This could be really bad.

Comment: It is showing your machine took up only around 16 GB total.
and nothing has been through ast0 interfaces yet.

What have you discovered from your networking issue and how much was the all of your bandwidth in total?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the mess just type:

```
sudo ifconfig as0t0 down
sudo ifconfig as0t1 down
```

etc., for `as0t2` and so on to `as0t15`.

Don't do it for `lo` or `eth0`.

I think that will clear it up. Why its doing that I have no clue.

Comment: The multiple `as0tX` interfaces might be from [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/commonly-asked-technical-questions/#Why_does_Access_Server_have_multiple_network_interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

From the output you have posted, most of the data is consumed on `eth0` interface. It is not a networking issue. Instead check the processes that are transmitting/receiving data. Use `netstat | findstr ESTABLISHED` to find connections established and `netstat -e` for interface statistics.